# how to display all image in array react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, display

how to display Img array all image in react js
***data******
import im1 from "../Image/10007.jpg"
export const Data =[
{
name:"aminur",

```
   Img:[im1,im1,im1]
}
```

]`enter code here`

code :

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Content.css"
import { Data } from './data'
const Content = () => {
  return (
    <div className='content'>
      {Data.map((item)=>{
        return(
            <div className='text'>
                <img src={item.Img[0]} alt="" />

                
            </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Content
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is how to display all the images under Img array which is inside an another array of objects.

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Content.css"
import { Data } from './data'
const Content = () => {
  return (
    <div className='content'>
      {Data.map((item)=>{
        return(
            <div className='text'>
              {item?.Img.map(image=>(
                <img src={image} alt="" />
              ))}
            </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Content
```